# Summary Display for grouped items in a datagrid

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor, ienumerable

I have a datagrid (radzen components) that I have grouped by staff member last name (column is call OwnerLName)

The grouping works fine and now I am trying to summarize the other columns in the table for each grouped staff member last name.

The radzen component examples website has the following code.

context.Data.Items.Cast().Sum(o => o.Freight)

I completely understand that it is used to cast each item in Order and sum up the freight.

My C# is very limited and I am not sure what 'context' is.

My table is called CrmTask

I am trying to count the number of times a specific column (first example is EventStep1Complete) equals true.

I have tried to use the application name, the table name, the database name, the grid name and none works.

So far I can only summarize the entire table and not by group.

if I use   .Data.Items.Cast().Count(o => o.EventStep1Complete == true)

I cannot figure out what I need to put in front of .Data.....

I have little experience with C#, so I apologize if I asked a stupid question.

Comment: Try following : var results =  context.Data.Items.GroupBy(x => x.Freight).Select(x => new {freight = x.Key, count = x.Count()).ToList();

Comment: ok, but what is context?  I don't use that term anywhere.  Is it the database, the table, the grid, or something else?  Nothing I use for context gets me .Data.Items.... if I use the name of my grid (gridRecap)  I can do this:  gridRecap.Data.Cast<CrmTask>().Count(o => o.EventStep1Complete == true)  which summarizes the entire table, not the groups...

Comment: You are using Entity were there is a mapping between c# classes and the database Tables/Fields.  The c# classes is the context.  When you created you project a Migration was performed which took you c# classes and created a database.  Not sure when this was performed.  You use to have two options 1) Code First 2) Database first.  The Database first option is no longer supported.  Code first meant you created your c# classes first and code would than create database.  Database first meant you would create you database and then code would create c# classes.

Comment: Context is class that contains the c# classes the are the tables in the database.  For example Public Class Context { public List<table1> table1 {get;set;} public List<table2> tables { get;set;} public List<table3> table3 {get;set;})  Public Class table1 { public string field1 {get;set} Public int field2 {get;set;}}